# How to split string in a sentence using php?

Tags: php, string, split

How to split a word in a string using php and store into two differebt variables $str1 , $str2

```
Input String : The encyclopedia project Wikipedia is the most famous wiki on the public web, but there are many sites running many different kinds of wiki software. Wikis can serve many different purposes both public and private, including knowledge management, notetaking, community websites and intranets. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access). For example, editing rights may permit changing, adding or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Other rules may also be imposed to organize content.<div class="new">Some Text Here! </div> 

Output String : 

$str1 : The encyclopedia project Wikipedia is the most famous wiki on the public web, but there are many sites running many different kinds of wiki software. Wikis can serve many different purposes both public and private, including knowledge management, notetaking, community websites and intranets. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access). For example, editing rights may permit changing, adding or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Other rules may also be imposed to organize content.

$str2 : <div class="new">Some Text Here! </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Next time be sure to add what you have tried and properly format your code.

Comment: Whit this update, my answer make no sense now. Next time, please be more descriptive in what you are trying to achieve. Do you always want to split it before the <div> ? Is it always a <div> ?

Comment: yes Fabien. I want to split the <div> content with <div> tag

Comment: I just edited my first answer

Answer (score 2):

First you can check where the piece you want to split at starts using strpos. So it would be in this case

```
$pos = strpos($string,"<");
```

Then you're going to want to use the substr function to split it accordingly.

```
$str1 = substr($string,0,$pos); //This takes everything from the start to the position indicated

$str2 = substr($string,$pos); //This takes everything from the position to the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

So find the position of `<div` first

```
$divpos = strpos(strtolower($InputString),"<div");
```

I used `strtolower` in case that you got `<DIV` instead of `<div`

And then, using substr will do the trick :

```
$str1 = trim(substr($InputString,0,$divpos));
$str2 = trim(substr($InputString,$divpos));
```

I used `trim` to remove any unwanted spaces.

Comment: Thanks Fabien. Its very useful for me.